# Transition not animating in IE9-11 when using calc

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to get IE10 to animate a change in width of an element so that it pushes another panel out of the way. I have a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/IxobULI/1/) demonstrating the basic idea. On Chrome, it animates just fine when you click the open and close links. In IE10, however, it just jumps to open and close. I think I have all the neccessary prefixing in--anyone know why it's not animating?

UPDATE: Tried giving the right side explicit pixel values for open and close states. Animated just fine. *shakes fist* Percentages....

UPDATE 2: Apparently %-to-% works, as does px-to-px, and %-to-px, and px-to-% but %-to-whatever-calc-is failed

UPDATE 3: Found [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/733978/css-animation-dont-accept-calc-as-property-values) at Connect, which seems to describe exactly this issue (except using keyframe animations instead of transitions). Status: "Resolved as Postponed". Damn it, IE.

**HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="body-container">
      <div id="left">
        <div id="nav">
          <h1>Nav</h1>

          <a href="#right">
            Close
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            Open
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="left-content">
          LEFT
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        RIGHT
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Less**:

```css
@nav-width: 54px;

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#body-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  #left,
  #right {
    height: 100%;
  }

  #left {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;

    #nav {
      width: @nav-width;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    #left-content {
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: orange;
    }
  }

  #right {
    width: 66%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transition: width 0.5s linear;
    transition: width 0.5s linear;

    &:target {
      width: calc(~'100% - @{nav-width}');
    }
  }
}
```

---

Simpler examples that show the issue with `calc` provided by other Stack Overflow users:

- http://jsfiddle.net/p6f0d3wb/
- http://jsfiddle.net/v7wdaoq1/

Comment: Why are you nesting rules inside other rules?

Comment: Why not? This isn't meant to be production code, I'm aware that nesting #id rules is redundant, I'm just demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm just noticed that you're using LESS. Can you add the proper tag?

Comment: LESS isn't really the issue here, I was just using it because I find it more handy than straight CSS. My using LESS is incidental here.

Comment: Well, LESS might be an issue here. Maybe it causes the problem with IE?

Comment: I'm pretty sure JSBin compiles the LESS down before rendering it, so IE shouldn't care/know.

Comment: But maybe there's an error in your LESS code? Maybe it's rendered someway that it's not supported by IE. Anyway, did you try to do it in pure CSS?

Comment: Have you already taken a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/ie-10-11-css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work

Comment: @sodawillow Yes, translateX won't work for the size of an element.

Comment: Maybe with `transform: scaleX(n)` then ?

Comment: @sodawillow That would seem to work but the element compresses in the center, keeping the original width. http://jsfiddle.net/p6f0d3wb/1/ Plus, I can't seem to get it to work well with calc anyway. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I understand better now. You're not doing it wrong, the element will keep occupying the original space. Maybe you could do the calculation with LESS instead ?

Comment: I've never worked with Less, but I would assume that it can't calculate 100% - 100px (or something similar) without either JavaScript or calc.

Comment: You're right, for now I didn't find a trick, even with 100vw :)

Comment: [looks like yo're trying to create something like this?](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/). But as it's currently written, it looks like an XY problem

Comment: @jbutler483 That's somewhat correct, but it pushes the content to the right instead of compressing the content on the right.

Comment: [see here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/umEgv) - it's 'compressing' the content on the right hand side

Comment: @jbutler483 That may be an alternative, but the ideal would be that the navigation is the same width without depending on screen size.

Comment: Incidentally, [there is no such thing as `-ms-transition`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). There was never a vendor prefixed version. This issue is also present in IE11.

Comment: Here is [an active bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814380/).

Answer (score 0):

### No calc was harmed in the creation of this example

Tested and working in IE11, Chrome and Firefox.

- The nav is brought outside of the `#left` container. Now we have `#nav`, `#left` and `#right`
- The nav is given `flex: 0 0 54px`. It will not grow or shrink from its default value of 54px.
- `#right` is given `width: 66%`
- On selection, `#right` is given `width: 100%` to take up the entire amount of space inside the flex container. `#left` is squeezed out and is hidden and the nav stays put because it has been told not to shrink.
- The `overflow: hidden` on `#left` prevents its contents from spilling out in IE11
- `#left` is given `min-width: 0` alongside its `flex: 1`, this ensures that it can be hidden (The flex items default `min-width` is handled differently in recent Firefox versions)

#### Complete Example

This example is made with vanilla CSS.

The height of the flex container has been given with `height: 100vh` for this example. This could be changed to `height: 100%` if needed.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#body-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
#nav {
  flex: 0 0 54px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#right {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
  width: 66%;
}
#right:target {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="body-container">
  <div id="nav">
    <h1>Nav</h1>
    <a href="#right">Close</a>
    <a href="#">Open</a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  
  <div id="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried this in IE11 and saw no transition effect. Is it working for you?

Comment: @Anonymous - You're right! I hadn't had a chance to test in IE11. It appears to not want to transition the flex property. I have made some changes and now the width is transitioned (with **no** calc needed); it **now works in IE11** :)

Comment: Yup, that seems to work. Annoying how IE hasn't fixed this issue for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround with max-width:

```
.test {
    background: #990000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: width 0.5s linear;
    max-width: calc(100% - 54px);
}
.test.alt {
    width:100%;
    max-width: calc(100% - 54px);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7wdaoq1/)