# CSS transitions with calc() do not work in IE10+

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

I am animating a container on mouseover from right to the left with CSS transitions. This works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer. The reason is that I am using (and need to use) calc() in my CSS left property.

**I created a live demo here: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4MsK8/)**

The CSS looks like this:

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 90%;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
div.translate-less {
    left: calc(90% - 4rem)
}
```

I am adding the class .translate-less on mouseover with jQuery:

```
$(document)
.on( 'mouseenter', 'div', function(){
    $(this).addClass('translate-less')
})
.on( 'mouseleave', 'div', function(){
    $('div').removeClass('translate-less');
})
```

Now I would like to have a smooth transition in Internet Explorer. For that, I would even ditch the calc() for these specific browsers and add a rule like `left: 85%;`. But IE 10 and 11 have [dropped support for conditional comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx) and there seems to be no way to target these browsers specifically. IE 10 can be targeted with the [-ms-high-contrast-hack](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/), but IE 11 cannot. I do not want to [use JavaScript](http://thebenlumley.com/how-to-target-ie-11-with-css/) to detect the browser because this seems even hackier than using CSS hacks.

Comment: what is the issue with just using left:85% since it will work with all browsers? Also why not just use .translate-less:hover instead of adding a class on mouseover.

Comment: Charles380, there is a significant difference between left:85% and left:90%-4rem. The sliding distance of the former is relative (big on wide viewports, small on narrow viewports), while the latter is absolute. This happens to be an important difference in my design. (Thanks for the :hover tip, but I need to use jQuery here for other reasons. Basically, I modify more elements than just this one and cannot target these with :hover.)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Maybe `transform: translateX()` can provide a work-around. Depending on the circumstances, using transforms and the right property might be better:

```
right: 10%;
transform: translateX(-4rem);
```

Here is a modified version of your script: http://jsfiddle.net/xV84Z/1/.

Alternatively, while you can't use `calc()` within a `translateX()` in IE (because of [a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform)), you can apply multiple `translateX()`s in a transform:

```
/* This */
transform: translateX(90%) translateX(-4rem);
/* is equivalent to this */
transform: translateX(calc(90% - 4rem));
```

(However, 90% in this case means 90% of the target, not the parent.)

Comment: Wow... this is a great answer! I had a related problem - I wanted to use calc() with `translateX`, but while it works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox - it doesn't work with IE. So, your solution of using **multiple** `translateX`s in a single transform is very handy! Just out of curiosity - do you know **why** it doesn't work in IE? Is that not part of the spec, or just a bug?

Comment: @mattstuehler [It's a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform)

Comment: so what is the solution if you need 90% of parent, not target?

Comment: I assume that `right: 10%;` is not working in your context.  What can you know about the parent? Is its width implicit or explicit? Are there things in the surrounding context you can know or assume? Or better yet, do you have an example?

Comment: Thank you! The second solution is way more performant if you animate/transform the property, because `right` triggers a repaint.