# Not possible to use CSS calc() with transform:translateX in IE

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to use calc() with transform:translateX in my CSS.

E.g.,

```css
#myDiv {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100% - 50px));
  -moz-transform: translateX(calc(100% - 50px));
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 50px));
}
```

While this works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox - it does not work in IE10 or IE11.

You can see a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SL2mk/9/

Is this impossible? Is it a bug in IE, or is `calc()` not supposed to work in this context?

For what it's worth - I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381301/49383) that you can "stack" `translateX` to acheive the same effect, and my testing seems to confirm this. I.e.,

```css
#div {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 50px));
}
```

is the same as:

```css
#div {
  transform: translateX(100%) translateX(-50px);
}
```

But I don't know if this is the best, most reliable, and future-proof way to do this.

I also know that it's possible to use `left` instead of `translateX`, but the latter is much smoother when used with transitions, since, as I understand it, it forces the use of the GPU to handle the animation.

Comment: [It's a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform), and [this question is a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/ie-10-11-css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work). Just use two `translateX`s, it's the best way

Answer (score 245, accepted):

This:

```
transform: translateX(100%) translateX(-50px);
```

gets compiled at parse time, but calc expression here :

```
transform: translateX(calc(100% - 50px));
```

has to be interpreted each time when browser needs that value. Result of the expression can be cached but I wouldn't rely on browsers to use such kind of optimizations.

So first one is better in the sense that a) it works now, b) is effective and c) it will work in future until the spec will be in effect.

Comment: This was a great workaround to an issue I was having with the YUI CSS compressor not handling a nested calc() expression correctly. Thanks!

Comment: This is by far the most helpful thing I've learned in a long time about CSS!

Comment: Wow, this is peculiar! It worked really well for me. Thank you.

Comment: Its silly, but the new information for me here is that is possible to use same type of transforms multiple times on an element! Thanks!

Comment: are the 2 translateX executed at the same time or one after another? Because, if one after another, also transitions properties would dubled, causing different effect than calc() usage.

Comment: @Stratboy  the reason of this "transitions properties would dubled" is not clear.

Comment: I mean, speed, easing, delay, etc. Maybe.

Comment: What @LucaReghellin is asking is a great question. I think what he means is: whether the transforms are 1) executed one after another in sequence, or 2) calculated beforehand and then executed once, could affect transition animations. For example, if #1, then it will be a single uniform transition. However, if #2, will the transition speed - say it's 1 second - apply to each transform (for 2 transforms, that would mean 2 seconds), or 1 second for both transforms, and how much time given to each transform, split 50/50?

Answer (score 11):

I just use them both with -ms- browser selector. It works perfectly.

```
-ms-transform: translateX(100%) translateX(-50px); /* IE 11 */
transform: translateX(calc(100% - 50px));
```

Comment: i confirm this works decently well. (i'm actually using something like `calc(912px - 50vw)` to prevent a sidebar from displaying on top of a dashboard unless you hover it.