# Internet Explorer 11 Not allowing calculation within @keyframe

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have a little bit of code that bounces some text back and forth within the width of a DIV.

While this example works in Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome it will not work within Internet Explorer 11.

The problem seems to be with the **calculation** that is being made within the @keyframe area of the code

```
@keyframes slidein {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 250px)); 
    }
}
```

Please see the JSFiddle for the full example : http://jsfiddle.net/Musicman/g7e34/5/

P.s The problem is nothing to do with me requiring -ms- vendor prefixes

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform) is apparently a bug since IE10 - and it's been closed (as won't fix) so I don't think we'll be seeing this work anytime soon.

Comment: It is still active here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814380/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work in IE11 (on W7 x64) with your jsfiddle by using the answer given at [IE 10 + 11: CSS transitions with calc() do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/ie-10-11-css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work):

```
@keyframes slidein {
    from {
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform:translateX(-100%) translateX(250px); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks pal... this is working perfectly, sadly tho for me .. one problem fixed and another problem created... IE ignoring my class.remove script.. Wow.. IE is not so good eh?

Comment: @Justin IE always was a tragedy.

Comment: Thanks! This also fix the exact similar issue in Safari 12.x and Safari STP 89 (STP 13.1).