# Positioning calc() smoothly into its correct position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using `calc()` as inline css. The positioning seems to be noticeable. Because after the page loads it jumps from the bottom of the page to its correct position. Is there a way I can do a easing transition or similar. So then it positions smoother rather than jumping bottom to its position.

```
<div style="top: calc(35%);"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a CSS transition?

Comment: @Alessio thanks. No, I haven't. That's one reason I posted it here. How can I do a transition to a `calc()`?

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using `calc` as no calculation is being done in your example? Couldn't the same be achieved with just `style="top: 35%;"`?

Comment: It is a transition on the `top` property, no matter how you defined it

Comment: @bekki The CSS transition need to be applied to the top property. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331008/using-calc-to-transition-width-and-height-in-ie

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: thanks. I wanted to position this div 35% from it's screen height. That's why I've used `calc()` for `top:`

Comment: so maybe you could use `top: 35vh`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan thanks. That has the same. But the positioning is noticeable. I'm looking to make it position into its correct position smoother rather than jumping from bottom to top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use calc for only percentages, but here's an example of a class change triggering a CSS transition 1 second after the code runs:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('d').className = 'ready';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#d {background: #ccc; position: absolute; transition: top 1s linear; top: 0}
#d.ready {top: calc(35%);}
```

```html
<div id="d">DIV</div>
```

Comment: Loos good thanks. I'll wait for a pure css based answer before I mark your answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)  That is a CSS-based answer though, I'm only using JS to change the class because transitions won't work if the class is set right away (it needs to have start and end values).

Comment: maybe instead of a transition an animation could be more suitable so js would be not needed.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes, it's an option. I went for the transition because OP said the div jumps from the bottom to the central position meaning there is something trigerring the change of the `top` value at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Change your style in this way:

```
<div style="top: 35%;transition: .5s;"></div>
```