# Transition Height with Calc() in IE10/11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

before we start I want to say I have looked at [Using calc() to transition width and height in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331008/using-calc-to-transition-width-and-height-in-ie) but my issue is to do with the Accepted answer to this question.

Now the accepted answer definitely works on IE 11 along with other browsers I have tested, however with the webapp I am creating I need to transition only the Height of a Div, not the width. So I re-created the accepted answers solution changing the `max-width` to `max-height`, but this does not seemingly work in the same way as the height will still not transition.

Here is my Fiddle of the modified accepted answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/esfqqm4p/

```
.container{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.doesntwork:hover {
    max-height: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.works:hover {
    height: 175px;
}
```

Why does max-height perform differently in this case compared to max-width? Is there something I've missed? Is there a solution to transitioning height in IE10/11?

Answer (score 0):

So I spent some time yesterday and today attempting multiple pure CSS solutions but to no avail. In the end I decided just to use the JQuery Animate function to achieve my goal which works great in IE.

Here's a fiddle showcasing the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/uwrosa3m/

```
function startAnim(){
    if(!$('.block').hasClass("shrunk")){
    $('.block').addClass("shrunk");
    $('.block').animate({ 'height': '50%' }, 500);
  }
  else{
    $('.block').removeClass("shrunk");
    var height = ($('.block').height() * 2) - 10;
    $('.block').animate({ 'height': height }, 500);
  }
}
```

Instead of using calc() in my CSS to calculate the height I simply let JQuery handle that problem.

If anyone can find a pure CSS solution then please post it and I'll accept it as an answer.