# transform translateY with calc not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-transforms

I have the following transform which does not seem to work in IE11.

Is there an alternative to get calc to work in IE11?

```
transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5rem))
-ms-transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5rem))
```

Comment: Possible related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/ie-10-11-css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
-ms-transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(5rem);
-webkit-transform:  translateY(-100%) translateY(5rem);
-moz-transform:  translateY(-100%) translateY(5rem);
transform:  translateY(-100%) translateY(5rem);
```

This is equal to calc. calc does not work on ie 11.

Comment: in the end I just used `transform: translateY(-120%);` above the calc one. as that transform did not work quite the same on IE

Comment: Thankyou Michael, you saved our bacon!