# Why does my toggle not work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am toggling an element out and back into screen. It works nicely but not in Explorer. How do I make it also explorer compatible. Can you please help?

See my example here:

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/s0f7n7n9/3/)

```
/*START makes text-over-photo div collapse and expand horizontally*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
        var $container = $('#text-over-photo-container');
        $container.toggleClass('hide2');
    });
});


$('#togglebutton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus');
});
```

Comment: This possible duplicate does in fact addresses the issue with using calc in those instances and suggests using `translateX` - It also references more information on why it doesn't work - [**IE 10 + 11: CSS transitions with calc() do not work**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/ie-10-11-css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work) - For you specifically using `transform: translateX(-90%);` seems to work ► https://jsfiddle.net/4joxxLvc/

Comment: However, rblarsen's answer maintains the margin of 60px, even in a responsive design. As where in your example the margin is variable/changes when the window is resized.

Comment: Hence I only commented and didn't provide an answer :)

Comment: Thank you, Fran!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try prefixing your `transition` and `transform`: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s0f7n7n9/4/)

**EDIT:** I just tested my fiddle in IE, and found out that the calc in the translate was the issue.
I have removed the calc and added a margin to even out the 60px, instead, which works in IE11: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s0f7n7n9/5/)