# CSS calc() operation not working properly on Edge browser

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I have a 3 column element on a page

```
<main>
    <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
    <section class="main-content"></section>
    <aside class="right-sidebar"></aside>
</main>
```

And have the following css rules:

```
main {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

main > * {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

aside.left-sidebar {
    max-width: 320px;
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.main-content {
    width: calc(100% - 800px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 65px;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

aside.right-sidebar {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
}
```

This works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on Microsoft Edge, anything am missing?

One thing I noticed on Edge upon checking its DevTools is that it will reverse the operation on the **calc()** function so instead of `width: calc(25% - 20px);` it'll  convert it to `calc(-20px + 50%)`
unsure if that's the culprit tho the result is the same I think.

**UPDATE**: Forgot to include that there's a max-width set on columns and `max-width:100%` is called when screen size is `@media screen and (max-width: 1440px)`.

Comment: Edge has issues with flex + calc, as noted here, https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc (not sure where that issue is documented, though).

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work-in-ie10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transitions with calc() do not work in IE10+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work-in-ie10)

Comment: I try to make a test with your code and it gave similar results in all 3 browsers. Here is the testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/QCy17ng4/341.png Can you try to show the snapshot of the issue? It can help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT updated my question. Will check it on my end. Thanks

Comment: I again made a test with your updated code and got this result. https://i.postimg.cc/3wHsz2dN/342.png Result still looks similar. I suggest you to provide a sample code which can produce the issue. Also post the snapshot can give more idea about the issue. Instead of max-width try to use only width and try to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible workaround that shouldn't be used

This only appears to be a problem with percentage widths, not viewport width units (`vw`). Here is a workaround that shouldn't be used:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside.left-sidebar {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: calc(25vw - 20px);
}

.main-content {
  background: green;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: calc(50vw - 20px);
  margin: 0 20px;
}

aside.right-sidebar {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
  <section class="main-content"></section>
  <aside class="right-sidebar"></aside>
</main>
```

---

#### What you should use

Since you're using flex, [use flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

- First and third column are given `flex: 1`
- Center column is given `flex: 2`
- Place the left and right margin on the center column
- The columns can be given individual max-widths
- No widths are given

This gives you the same ratio, no need for `calc`.

#### Example

Note: I have removed the default margin on the body and given main `100vh` so it has a height for this example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside.left-sidebar {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.main-content {
  background: green;
  flex: 2;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

aside.right-sidebar {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
  <section class="main-content"></section>
  <aside class="right-sidebar"></aside>
</main>
```

Comment: In my case the two sidebars have different sizes. How would you handle that?

Comment: @leonardeveloper - you can change the sidebar widths with different `flex` values. See [the MDN docs page here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Comment: @leonardeveloper - not sure what more you are trying to achieve. If you look at the flex values example in my answer, you'll see the `max-width`'s restrict the columns to different widths when appropriate. Make it full size and you'll see it.